# Hartshorne Exercise III 10.6: etale covering of the nodal cubic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is stated as follows:

> Let Y be the plane nodal cubic curve $y^2=x^2(x+1)$. Show that $Y$ has a finite etale covering $X$ of degree $2$, where $X$ is a union of two irreducible components, each one isomorphic to the normalization of $Y$.

Well, its normalization map is: $\mathbb A_k^1 \to Y$ where $t$ is mapped to $(t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$. Since parabola is isomorphic to the affine line, and they can intersect at two points easily, I can consider $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2)$, and set a map $f:X\to Y$ by $(s,t)\to (s^2-1,st)$. Thus $X$ is the union of two parabolas, and each one is mapped to $Y$ as a normalization.

$f$ is flat by chapter 3, proposition 9.7 of Hartshorne. But it seems that $f$ is not etale for the following reasons:

If $f$ is etale, then all its fibers are finite(trival) and reduced.(this is a well-known equivalence of being unramified, see Liu Qing Lemma 3.20 on page 139). But when I consider the point $P=(-1,0)$ on $Y$, its fiber is $(k[s,t]/(t^2-1,s^2,st))_P$. $s$ is trivially a nilpotent element, hence the ring is not reduced.

Did I get something wrong? Could you point out my mistakes and help me modify it? Besides, if you have a reference for this etale map(include detailed calculations) could you share it here? If you have your own way to construct $X$, it would also be nice if you could post the construction here. All helps are appreciated!

Comment: $s$ is not nilpotent, it's actually zero. $1\cdot s=t^2\cdot s=0$ in the quotient ring. You needn't worry here :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering. For the localization I mean : Let $S=\left(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))\right)\setminus P$, and $(k[s,t]/(t^2-1,s^2,st))_P=S^{-1}k[s,t]/(t^2-1,s^2,st)$. But how can I show $t^2$ is in the image of $S$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - there's no need to localize when computing a fiber. The fiber over $(-1,0)$ is the spectrum of the tensor product $k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2)\otimes_{k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)} k$, where $k=(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2))/(\bar{x}+1,\bar{y})$. As $M\otimes_R R/I\cong M/IM$, the tensor product simplifies to $k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2,s^2,st)$. But this latter ideal is exactly $(t^2-1,s^2,st)$ by subtracting off multiples of $s^2$ from the first generator, and therefore by the first comment the fiber is the spectrum of $k[t]/(t^2-1)$, or two points.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.... Just $s(t^2-1)=0$.... Sorry for asking it, and thank you for your detailed answer again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me record the discussion from the comments as an answer.

To compute the fiber over $P=(-1,0)$, take the spectrum of the tensor product $$k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2)\otimes_{k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)} k$$ where $k$ is considered a $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$-algebra as $(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2))/(x+1,y)$. Since $M\otimes_R R/I\cong M/IM$, this tensor product is isomorphic to $k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2,s^2,st)$. Subtracting off multiples of $s^2$ from the first generator, we find that the ideal $(t^2-(s^2-1)^2,s^2,st)$ is equal to the ideal $(t^2-1,s^2,st)$. This means that $t^2=1$ in the quotient, so $1\cdot s =t^2\cdot s =0$, and therefore $s=0$. So the fiber over $P$ is the spectrum of $k[t]/(t^2-1)$, or two points, just like we want.

---

Added later: By the way, your claim that $f$ is flat by proposition III.9.7 is not correct - $Y$ is not regular, so this proposition doesn't apply. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736736/%c3%89tale-covering-of-nodal-cubic-curve-hartshorne-exercise-10-6) for more details about how to prove $f$ is flat.